# Connect to mysql DB through ssh (java)

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, rds

I need to connect to Mysql RDS DB through ssh connection, what i have tried is to open an ssh tunnel and then connect to that DB, but it did not work.

Below is my code:

```
 int lport = 3306;
    String host = "10.254.64.135";
     String rhost = "localhost";
     int rport = 8000;
    String user = "ubuntu";
    String dbuserName = "someusername";
     String dbpassword = "somepassword";
    String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://somedbhost.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
     String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String driverName2 = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";

    Session session = null;

   try {

       final java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
       config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
       final JSch jsch = new JSch();
       session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
       jsch.addIdentity("C:\\Users\\rop\\workspace\\awskey.pem");
       session.setConfig(config);
       session.connect();
       System.out.println("Connected through SSH");
       final int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(rport, host,lport );
       System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + rhost + ":" + rport);
       System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

       //mysql database connectivity
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/" + db;
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);
       System.out.println("Mysql Database connection established");
       System.out.println("DONE");
```

The above code crash with below exception, and crashs in this line "con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);":

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

mean while when we connect from mysql workbench it does connect normally, below a snapshot:

[image]

Please note that the ssh host ip is different than the db host ip

Thanks.

Comment: Because localhost:8000  is the tunnel,  that's where your jdbc should connect to . Probably due to confusion in  lport and rport naming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the hostname and port in the JDBC url with `localhost` and the local port you're forwarding from, which you call `rport`:

`dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport;`

Also, I'm not sure if the MySQL JDBC Driver supports connecting to the database server without specifying a database name:

`dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/yourdatabasename";`

Also, if the MySQL Server is not running on the same machine as the SSH server, make sure you can connect to the database server from the SSH server.
MySQL doesn't allow remote connections by default.